# Android Image view border is not showing

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to show an image border from network image. To test this in offline I have created a view with dummy image. but view shoing fine in android studio editor but in real device the image border is not showing.

this is my editor view

[image]

this is my device view

[image]

activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorViolet">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/theme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/border_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/border_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/border_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/border_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image_border"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/border_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/view_border_gradient"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img_default" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/aura"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img_default" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/badge"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/charms"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
            android:src="@drawable/img_default" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/charms"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/image"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/badge"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
            android:src="@drawable/img_default" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/badgeTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/badge"
            android:textColor="@color/colorHint"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/badge"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/badge"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/badge"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/charmTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/charms"
            android:textColor="@color/colorHint"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/charms"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/charms"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/charms"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/close"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:tint="@color/colorRed"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cancel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/close"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/addFriend"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp"
            android:text="UserName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/viewProfile"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/addFriend"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/close"
            android:text="User Full Name"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewProfile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/view_round_sky"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/addFriend"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/addFriend"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgViewProfile"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/view_round_white"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                android:paddingEnd="3dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_view" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgViewProfile"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:text="@string/view_profile"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/addFriend"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/view_round_blue"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewProfile">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgViewProfileAdd"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/view_round_white"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                android:paddingEnd="3dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_add" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgViewProfileAdd"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:text="@string/add_as_friend"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/view_round_yellow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/addFriend"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/addFriend"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/addFriend">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgMessage"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/view_round_white"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                android:paddingEnd="3dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_message" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgMessage"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:text="@string/messages"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/gift"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/view_round_orange"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/addFriend"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/addFriend"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgGift"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/view_round_white"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                android:paddingEnd="3dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_gift" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgGift"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:text="@string/gift"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/block"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/view_round_red"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/addFriend"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/addFriend"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gift">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBlock"
                android:layout_width="21dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/view_round_white"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:paddingStart="3dp"
                android:paddingEnd="3dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_black" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgBlock"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:text="@string/block"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/groupButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="addFriend,message,gift,block" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/badge_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="badgeTitle,badge"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/charms_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="charms,charmTitle"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Test.java

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
}
```

}

this is the Border image file to used in the layout file

[image]

Comment: Try setting width and height of ImageVIew to `match_parent`.
It's probably because the image size is smaller than your view.

Comment: @ali73 thank you for replay, but if I do border-image height match_parent then the border-image is not constant to the content. I need to border-image adjust the height according to the content

Comment: It works on my phone.

Have you tried giving margin to the `ImageView`?

Comment: @ali73 do, provided xml is working on your phone without any change? 
which image view show i give margin   android:id="@+id/theme" ?

Comment: I had some errors about `start`s and `end`s so I had to add left and right. But yes it worked.
And I mean set margin for Imageview with id `@+id/theme` which contains the border image.You're aligning it to the FrameLayout and I thought it may be under the FrameLayout.

I think it would be easier to turn root `RelativeLayout` to `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: @ali73 thank you for you feedback. I have found out that the layout work fine to device with "android 10" but the border image is not showing in "android 5 (lolipop)". but I have no idea how to make it backward compatible

Comment: @ali73 thank you for your support, I have figured out glide cache is causing the problem, in my device with android lolipop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glide cache is causing the problem. It is now fixed after restarting the app